# How to add other data to Quickbook with qbXML

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I try this code it's work.(now, I can add Name : TestCustomer3)
And I want to add other data to Quickbook.
Can you Help me about qbXML Language.

Example : I want to add "Company Name", "Full Name", "Bill To"

***Example Code***

```
string input =   @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                      <?qbxml version=""2.0""?>
                    <QBXML>
                    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError=""stopOnError"">
                    <CustomerAddRq requestID=""15"">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                    <Name>TestCustomer3</Name> <!-- required -->
                    </CustomerAdd>
                    </CustomerAddRq>
                    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                    </QBXML>";
```

Answer (score 7):

The appropriate place to find this information is in the QuickBooks OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

To use the un-*Intuit*-ive QuickBooks OSR (pun intended) you should:

- Use the "Select Message" drop-down box from the top of the screen to choose a command/request type
- Click the "XML Ops" tab to view the XML request and response

Note that the XML request/response will be jumbled together a little, so make sure you look at the XML carefully to determine where the request ends, and the response starts.

We also have some other [QuickBooks qbXML examples](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests) on our QuickBooks integration wiki.

Answer (score 2):

The info can be found by reviewing the on screen reference for QBXML

https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

thanks